# javascript function as object

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

I know that that functions are treated as objects in JavaScript and was wondering if that is what made the following possible.

```
var foo = function () {
    return "bar";
};

foo.baz = "ooga";
```

If you call foo(), it will return "bar", and calling foo.baz will give "ooga".  How is this possible (a function having a property), and is this good programming practice?

Comment: `is this good programming practice?` - to answer this, consider that a function already has several properties to begin with ... `arguments`, `caller`, `callee`, `name` and `length` - not to mention all the "standard" Object properties and methods, and other methods like `call`, `apply`, `bind`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in Javascript a function IS actually an object, and to be more specific it is a "Function Object". This is why you can assign properties to it, however the difference between a Function Object and Classic Object is that a function can execute code AND have properties assigned to it.

Edit with example:

// Valid Syntax

```
var foo = function() {
    return 'hi';
};
```

// Throws Console Error

```
var foo = {
    bar: return 'hi'
};
```

A classical javascript object cannot execute something like a return statement in contrast to foo() which can, however you can assign both 'foos' a property with foo.baz.

Comment: Thank you for selecting my answer, glad to be of help!